# Tomcat 7 logging maxDays configuration to delete logs is not working

Tags: logging, tomcat7

I tried configuring tomcat 7 logging.properties file with maxdays configuration to delete log files after n days but it didn't work. Below is the logging.properties file changes:

```
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.
**# Adding log purging rule
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 1**

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.
**# Adding log purging rule
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 1**

3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = manager.
**# Adding log purging rule
3manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 1**

4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
**# Adding log purging rule
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 1**

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

Answer (score 1):

Closing the loop as I am using older version of Tomcat 7